# init_if_needed anchor-lang version

Tags: anchor-lang

to use the init_if_needed feature, i put in my Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.25.0", features = [ "init_if_needed" ] }
anchor-spl = "0.24.2"
mpl-token-metadata = { version = "1.2.5", features = [ "no-entrypoint" ] }
```

and get anchor build error:

```
error: failed to select a version for `anchor-lang`.
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey looks like the dependencies are not correct anchor-lang 0.25 expects also anchor-slp 0.25. Also it should be init-if-needed not init_if_needed try

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = {version = "0.25.0", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
anchor-spl = "0.25.0"
mpl-token-metadata = { version = "1.2.5", features = [ "no-entrypoint" ] }
```

You can check the correct dependencie here: https://crates.io/crates/anchor-spl/0.25.0/dependencies

Comment: ```versions that meet the requirements `^0.25.0` are: 0.25.0

Comment: how do i update the anchor in the project

Comment: anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.24.2

Comment: i guess i stopped where the anchor book said i should uninstall npm and use avm. do they really mean i should entirely remove nodejs from my system? seems wrong.

Comment: all this was because i wanted the init_if_needed feature. are we advised to make the client take responsibility for creating associated token accounts?

Comment: yikes _ is not - in cargo.toml. well at least i can build now. thanks guys. still, are we advised against init-if-needed?

Comment: init_if_needed can make you vunerable to reinitialization attacks. Yes usually the ata is created in the client i think.